# Terminology for "quasi-constant" functors

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, functors

Is there a commonly agreed upon terminology for a functor $F:A\to B$ such that
all $F(X)$ are isomorphic in $B$, where $X$ is an object of $A$ ? I would guess something like "quasi-constant" or "essentially constant" would make sense, but no result came up when I tried to search for it.

I'm especially interested in a terminology that applies when $F$ is not isomorphic to a constant functor (for instance, if $A=B$ is the category of sets with $n$ elements, then the identity functor is "quasi-constant" in the above sense since all sets with $n$ elements are isomorphic, but it is not isomorphic as a functor to any constant endofunctor of $A$).

Comment: Do you also want $F$ to take all arrows of $A$ to an isomorphism in $B$? In that case, if $A$ is connected, it is just a 'functor to a subgroupoid of $B$'. Otherwise I guess it doesn't have any name..

Comment: In the case I'm interested in, $A$ is a (non-connected) groupoid, so this is automatic, but I'm really curious about any reference to a reasonable variation of the notion.